# Cannot extend volume for Windows 10 VM after allocating extra space?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a windows 10 VM in a VMWare Workstation.  I just allocated an extra 50 gigabytes via the VM settings when it was off.  I turned on the VM, opened up Computer Management->Disk Management, clicked Actions->Refresh and I do see the extra space there now under Disk 0 as 'unallocated'.  I tried right clicking my C:\ Drive to `Extend Volume` but it was greyed out.  I tried doing this again, running Computer Management as `Admin`, I still see the free allocated space, but Extend Volume is still greyed out for me.  What am I missing?  How can I extend the C drive to use this extra space?

Edit: Screenshot -
[image]

Comment: Please add a full screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: Just attached a screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EFI partition is located below the `C:` partition.
To append the Unallocated space to `C:` requires it to be located
following `C:`.

You cannot move the EFI partition via Disk Management.
You will need to use a bootable ISO of a third-party partition editor.

To choose a partition editor, see for example the article
[11 Best Free Disk Partition Software Tools](https://www.lifewire.com/free-disk-partition-software-tools-2624950).

Set the ISO as the boot device of the VM. boot it and use to move the
EFI partition to the end of the disk.
This will implicitly relocate the Unallocated space to below `C:`.

Remove now the boot ISO and reboot normally.
Disk Management will now be able to extend `C:`.

Take a backup of the VM before doing the above, just in case.

Comment: Ok I will try it.  So this means that the 515 MB partition between my C: and the unallocated space is the issue, that is what needs to be moved and is the EFI - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I used the MiniPartition Tool, the first software on that list, and it was very simple.  Right clicked my C Drive, extend volumne, it knew to grab from the unallocated space and took care of it for me without having to reboot from ISO or manually needing to move the EFI.  Just had to click apply.  Thanks for your help.